# Justification for this manipulation in a proof of the first variation of energy formula

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As a part of my current homework assignment, I am to derive the first variation of energy identity. Working out the problem with my friends, we came to exactly the same argument as presented in [these notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ewangzuoq/635W12/Notes/Lec%2024.pdf) (I have cut out some irrelevant parts from the presentation there, but kept the explanation of terminology and notation; at any rate, I am just using the notes to save myself the work of typing the whole thing).

> [image]
>
> [image]

I understand every step except the second:

> $\color{blue}{\bf \large (3)}$    $\nabla$ is a metric connection and $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ is symmetric
>
> $\color{blue}{\bf \large (4)}$    $\nabla$ is torsion-free (this is mentioned above: "where in the fourth equality...")
>
> $\color{blue}{\bf \large (5)}$    $\nabla$ is a metric connection
>
> $\color{blue}{\bf \large (6)}$    fundamental theorem of calculus

**What is the justification for step $\color{red}{\bf (2)}$?**

We have an ordinary scalar function on $[a,b]\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, which for convenience let's name $h$:
$$h(t,s)=\langle \dot{\gamma}_s(t),\dot{\gamma}_s(t) \rangle.$$
We take the partial derivative of $h$ w.r.t. $s$, which is again a scalar function on $[a,b]\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Now, I'm fine with the equality
$$\dot{\gamma}_s(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},$$
but how exactly does the differentiation $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}$ get turned into $\nabla_{\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**. Apparently the question is now clear to the OP, but anyway I've decided to summarize the discussion that occurred here for those who are not interested in reading the whole lot.

As the OP commented below @Ted's answer,

> But isn't $\nabla$ the connection on M, whereas $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\rangle$ is still a scalar function on $[a,b]\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$? How can we apply $\nabla$ to it?

After some thought I've realized that we all tried to justify the step (2) which turned out to be wrong and unnecessary. In fact, that comment reveals that merely the domain of the derivative is not correct.

The calculation is still fine despite of the problem with the second step because one simply has to use the fact that 
$$
\frac{d}{d s} \langle X, Y \rangle = \langle D_s X, Y \rangle + \langle X, D_s Y \rangle
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields along a curve with parameter $s$, and $D_s$ is the covariant derivative along the curve (see e.g. Lemma 5.2 of J.M.Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds", p.67). Now I think that Proposition 2.2 in M.P. do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry", p.50, states this fact even in in more suitable form, because in Lee's book we have to return to Lemma 4.9 on p. 57, part (c) that implies that in $X$ is an extendible vector field along the curve then for any extension $\widetilde{X}$ of this field we have
$$
D_s X(s) = \nabla_{\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}}  \widetilde{X}
$$
*along the curve*.

I keep the text below for the sake of completeness.

---

I would say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$  at $s=0$ is the same as the variation vector $V$, and for a scalar $h$ we can say that $V\,h = \nabla_V h$

**Edit**. Let me make my remark more convincing.

The partial derivative of a scalar $h(t,s)$ w.r.t. $s$ is precisely the covariant derivative of $h$ along the curve $p_t (s)$ (for each $t$ fixed). This is just because covariant derivatives of functions (scalars) are the same as the directional derivatives (as @Ted correctly pointed), and they are the same as the Lie derivatives, and the exterior... - they all agree on functions.

By definition, the variation vector field $V$ is the pushforward of the coordinate vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$, that is
$$
V := \mathrm{d}f \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}
$$
so we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} h = \mathrm{D}_s h = \nabla_V h
$$

Here is the picture:
[image: Variation of a curve]

Comment: I think the reason I'm concerned with this identification is that, as far I know, we are not assuming that $f$ is even locally a diffeomorphism - normally, I would expect that we would identify $h$ with the scalar function $h\circ f^{-1}$ on $M$. Indeed, suppose we take an arbitrary function $g:M\to\mathbb{R}$; then by definition, don't we have $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\bigg|_{(t_0,s_0)}\right)(g)= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_{(t_0,s_0)}\right)(g\circ f)\quad ?$$

Comment: Think your $h$ defined on $M$, so that $f^* h = h \circ f$ is defined for any smooth $f$. And don't forget the Chain Rule.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something really obvious, but I don't see how $h$ can be defined on $M$. For instance, what if for all $s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, $\gamma_s$ is the same curve as $\gamma_0$, just parametrized differently? Then to each point on (the image of) that curve, you'd have different tangent vectors you'd want to assign, and hence different values of $h$. Specifically, if $\gamma_{s_0}(t_0)=\gamma_{s_1}(t_1)$ but $\dot{\gamma}_{s_0}(t_0)\neq\dot{\gamma}_{s_1}(t_1)$ would we assign $h(t_0,s_0)$ or $h(t_1,s_1)$ to the point $\gamma_{s_0}(t_0)=\gamma_{s_1}(t_1)$ of $M$?

Comment: @Zev Sorry, you are right: $h$ is defined on the rectangle.

Comment: In fact, I believe now that you've spotted a sloppy step in the presented calculation. It is better to use directly $\frac{d}{d s} \langle X, Y \rangle = \langle \nabla_V X, Y \rangle + \langle X, \nabla_V Y \rangle $, as in Lemma 5.2 of J.M.Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds", p.67. Effectively, you don't need the step (2) at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I agree with your update to the answer - step (2) was just wrong as stated. My only remaining concern is, how do we know $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,s_0)$ is an extendible vector field along the curve $\gamma_{s_0}(t)$ for each $s_0\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, which we would need in order to turn
$$\int_0^1\langle D_s\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial t},\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\rangle\,dt$$
into
$$\int_0^1\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}}\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial t},\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}\rangle\,dt$$
I think it needn't be extendible.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Sure, you are right, but the point is that the set of variations that produce extendible fields is in a suitable sense "open", and integrating we may care only on the things that hold "almost everywhere". More precisely, first look at constant variations: $V=0$ and the identity is trivially satisfied. Next suppose that the variation is not identically constant: choose maximal subsegments with this property. Compactness and continuity will ensure that we get a finite number of subsegments of $[a,b]$ with $\epsilon$-s such that the variation is good enough. Etc...

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\nabla_X h=dh(X)$ is just the directional derivative. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ is the vector field giving the $s$ variation.

Comment: But isn't $\nabla$ the connection on $M$, whereas $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}\rangle$ is still a scalar function on $[a,b]\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$? How can we apply $\nabla$ to it?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I have to run, but quick thoughts: Check John Lee's Riemannian Manifolds book about covariant differentiation along curves.  This lets us apply the connection to "vector fields along curves" (which, strictly speaking, are not vector fields).

Comment: You can apply the covariant derivative to tensor fields of all orders, including those of order $0$, i.e., functions!

Comment: @Zev We (implicitly) **pull back** the geometric structures and the given quantities from $M$ to $[a,b]\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, so the things get *identified*. As I explain in my answer $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ becomes $V$.

Comment: @Jesse, Ted: If you get a chance, please take a look at my comment on Yuri's answer; my sense is that it's at the center of whatever my confusion is.