# Why does $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ make a good criterion for integrability?

Tags: calculus

That is

> $f$ is integrable on $[a,b] \iff \forall\epsilon>0, \exists P$ of $[a,b]$ such that
>
> $$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$$

I was thinking that a better definition would be if $U(f,P) = L(f,P)$, but I was corrected that it wouldn't work well for a curve like $f(x) = x$. The geometry just doesn't work.

On the other bound, saying that given any positive number, I can find a partition such that the difference $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ is bounded doesn't feel like a strong enough condition for integrability. Isn't the goal of analysis is always to make $\epsilon$ as small as possible, and possibly $0$?

Please see my other question on [A terminology to analysts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427844/a-terminology-to-analysts) for possible relevance. Thank you

Comment: Saying that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \varepsilon$ is saying exactly what you are looking for. No matter how small we make $\varepsilon$, we will be able to find some partition that makes the upper and lower sums differ by at most that value.

Comment: But we still an error of epsilon. I was hoping for a more error free definition. I was satisified with $\sup (L) = \inf (U)$

Comment: If $U(f,P) \neq L(f,P)$ for all $P$, then $U(f,P) - L(f,P) > 0$.Thus, given $\epsilon < \inf( U(f,P) - L(f,P) )$, there is no $P$ that will satisy $U(f,P)-L(f,p) < \epsilon$. So, the above two definitions mean the same thing.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @sidht But you can make the error **as small as you want**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above: Saying that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a partition P such that $U(f,P)−L(f,P)<\varepsilon$ is saying exactly what you are looking for. No matter how small we make $\varepsilon$, we will be able to find some partition that makes the upper and lower sums differ by at most that value.

Answer (score 4):

> *Isn't the goal of analysis is always to make $\epsilon$ as small as possible, and possibly 0?*

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what $\epsilon$ stand for here. **You are given** $\epsilon>0$ and you want to make **something** smaller than this $\epsilon >0$. Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192883/whats-wrong-with-this-backwards-definition-of-limit/192985#192985) can clear some of this out.

---

> *Why does $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ make a good criterion for integrability?*

Because

> **THM** Let $x,y$ be arbitrary real numbers. If $x<y+\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon >0$, then $x\leq y$.

**P** By contradiction. Suppose $x>y$. Then $x-y>0$. Take $\epsilon=x-y$. The above gives $x<y+\epsilon=y+x-y=x$ which is impossible. It must be the case $x\leq y$.

Note that since $\sup L\leq \inf U$ is always true, the criterion gives that $\inf U\leq \sup L$ which means $\sup L=\inf U$ and $f$ is integrable.

---

Now, proving that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $P=P_\epsilon$ such that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$ is usually **easier** than proving $\sup L=\inf U$ *directly*, in particular when the function is not given explicitly (say, if we want to prove $f$ is integrable when it is continuous) or any other cases where $f$ is in incognito.

Answer (score 1):

This is another extended comment, rather an answer.

I would just like to point out the the following two statements are totally different:

> - (1) $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ partition $P$ such that $$U(f,P) - L(f,P ) < \epsilon$$
> - (2) $\exists$ partition $P$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$:
>   $$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon.$$

In (1), the partition $P$ depends on $\epsilon$.  It might be more accurate to write $P$ as $P_\epsilon$ to remind ourselves of this fact.

In (2), there is a single partition $P$ -- independent of $\epsilon$ -- such that for all $\epsilon > 0$: $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ is satisfied.  In **this** situation, *because* the partition $P$ is independent of $\epsilon$, we can conclude that $U(f,P) = L(f,P)$.

> **Example:** Contrast the following two statements.  Think about how they are radically different:
>
> - (A) For all $x > 0$, there exists $y > 0$ such that $x < y$.
> - (B) There exists $y > 0$ such that for all $x > 0$: $x < y$.
>
> Note that (A) is obviously **true** (for any $x> 0$, there's always some number that's bigger), while (B) is obviously **false** (there is no single number $y$ bigger than *every* real number).

Comment: Jesse, could you take a look at my latest comment here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366103/justification-for-this-manipulation-in-a-proof-of-the-first-variation-of-energy/366113#comment927302_366113 I'm not sure about the extendability of these vector fields.